# node.js callback of an export typeerror undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I'm having difficulties getting a value returned from this function in a separate file called InfoHandler.js which gets included in my second file.

```
module.exports = {
    getInfo : function (val, callback) {
            jsonRPC.getInfo(function(json){
                    Data1 = json.result[2];
                    Data2 = json.result[0];
                    Data3 = val;
                    json = JSON.stringify(json);
                    console.log(json);
                    callback(json)
            });
    },
```

I want to use this like this:

```
require("InfoHandler.js");

var Info = InfoHandler.getInfo('50');
```

Info should now contain the json string which gets prepared from the getInfo function via the callback. Unfortunately I get:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

for the callback.

It's most likely an Async IO Problem, can someone give me a hint ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an async IO problem, you are trying to call `undefined` as a function. You aren't passing a callback to `getInfo` so `callback` is `undefined`. Instead, do something like this:

```
InfoHandler.getInfo('50', function(json) {
  console.log(json);
});
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks a lot, I just waisted 1 hour trying to get that running like "a function" as you already mentioned. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a callback function to `getinfo()`.

Instead of:

```
var Info = InfoHandler.getInfo('50');
```

Try:

```
InfoHandler.getInfo('50', function(Info) {
    //Use Info here.
});
```